# jquery .css() command inserts style into DOM, but doesn't take effect until page resizes

Tags: jquery, css

I have a script that centers an element upon load and resize:

```
function centerMe() {
  $('.centerme').each(function(){
    var imgw = $(this).width();
    $(this).css('margin-left', '-'+imgw/2+'px');
  });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  centerMe();
  $(window).resize(function(){
      centerMe();
  });
});
```

Strangely enough, on Chrome and Firefox in OSX, this function does, and doesn't, work. Though it loads the styling into the DOM, the browser does not take it into effect until the browser is resized or the page is refreshed.

What can be causing this?

Edit: This fixes the problem but creates a bigger one:

```
function centerMe() {
  $('.centerme').each(function(){
    $(this).load(function(){
      var imgw = $(this).width();
      $(this).css('margin-left', '-'+imgw/2+'px');
    });
  });
}

centerMe();

$(window).resize(function(){   
    centerMe();
});
```

Now the function properly centers the image on load, but fails to recalculate on resize :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because `$(document).ready` doesn't wait for the **images** to be loaded. So, when you do `var imgw = $(this).width();` the image hasn't always finished loading, and `imgw` is probably `0` or `undefined`.

What you could do is to use `$(window).load` instead.

**But** maybe you don't need jQuery at all! Considering you want your 3 images to be of full height *and* centered horizontally, just use:

`section.top .feature img {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}`

It will move your images to the left by half of their width.

Comment: Is there a fallback for ie8?

Comment: @invot see my comment

Answer (score 2):

Try taking the resize listener outside of DOM ready, and add a trigger to it.

```
$(window).resize(function(){   
    // code here
}).trigger('resize');
```

Also, try `$(window).load` instead of document ready. The DOM might not have the image width data yet.

```
$(window).load(function(){   
    centerMe();
})
```

Comment: If you can get it online, I can look at the timeline waterfall and see when functions are being called, or what might be preventing it. Hard to debug otherwise :-/

Comment: I'm editing the code now... fixed the problem but created a worse one. Let me revert it... try it now.

Comment: Post what you changed between those two updates and we could probably narrow it down

Comment: Also - add `console.log('resizing')` in the `centerMe()` function

Comment: Did so... testing it myself.

Comment: Looks like that solved it (just as someone else came to point it out as well). Now add some finesse by initially hiding the images in that big area and fading/animating them in or something nice so it doesnt do the jolt from right to left. Alternative, you could use some CSS transforms to center it like `transform: translateX(50%); left:-50%;`, and then only use the javascript after a modernizr check for older browsers.